# Jade block extend for each item in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

What am I doing wrong?

test.jade

```html
doctype !!! 5
html(lang="en-us")
    head
        title test
        h1 Information;
    body
        block testcontent
        form(method="post")
            input(type="button", value="refresh")
```

testcontent.jade

```html
extends test

append testcontent
    br
    p test #{title}
```

routing handler;

```js
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {  
            res.render('test');
});

app.post('/search', function(req, res) {  
    table.find().sort({created:1}).toArray(function(err, items) { 
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.render('testcontent', {title:items._id});
        }
    });
});
```

Trying to make it write 'test' and the title for each item in my database. I click 'refresh' in the page, nothing happens.

When the user sends a POST using the refresh button, it's meant to get every entry's _id in my database and stick it in an array with table.find().sort({created:1}).toArray()

Then I wanted it to render testcontent for each entry, res.render('testcontent', {title:items._id}); which should push out several entries of "test exampleTitle" on new lines.

Then that goes into the testcontent block in the first file, which can now be 'updated' every time the user clicks refresh.

Right?

But it doesn't work, no errors thrown, it just doesn't add the "test title" text to the /search route like I want it to.

I'm using Node.js/express and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if your form is submitted? Change the type of the button to submit from button and that will submit the form. And in your route handler, I see you are passing only one title to your template, so you will see only one line in your page. If you want one line per entry, you should pass the whole array to your template and iterate using the 'each' construct in your jade template

Comment: Oh, gotcha! Going to fix some async problems too, my function renders before it gets the signal that the DB is done finding/sorting the data.